# Share variables between modules

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x, module

I have this situation:

library_file1.py:

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        print("bar")

    def baz(self):
        pass
```

project_file.py:

```
from library_file1 import A
class B(A):
    def baz(self):
        print(the_variable)
```

library_file2.py:

```
from project_file import B

the_variable = 7
b = B()
b.foo()   # prints "bar"
b.baz()   # I want this to print "7", but I don't know how
```

How do I allow code to be written in `project_file.py` that can access variables from library_file2.py? The only solution I can think of is this:

project_file.py:

```
from library_file1 import A
class B(A):
    def baz(self, the_variable):
        print(the_variable)
```

library_file2.py:

```
from project_file import B

the_variable = 7
b = B()
b.foo()
b.baz(the_variable)
```

but this feels awkward and doesn't scale to many variables like `the_variable`.

Comment: You can use list of variables `b.baz( [var1, var2] )` or dictionary `b.baz( {'var1':7, 'var2':9} )` and then you have to rebuild `baz()`

Comment: @furas But then the variables would have to be used as `the_variable[7]` which is quite unclear. I could pass an instance of a custom class, and do `the_variable.var1` which would be better, but I'd still like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Quite easy: you need the variable to be in `project_file.py` instead of `library_file2.py`.
Change `project_file` to:

```
from library_file1 import A
the_variable = None

class B(A):
    def baz(self):
        print(the_variable)
```

And then in `library_file2`:

```
import project_file
from project_file import B

project_file.the_variable = 7
b = B()
b.foo()   # prints "bar"
b.baz()   # prints "7"
```

Using an argument is also a good solution (you should avoid globals as much as you can).

---

There is no such a thing as a truly *global* variable in python. Variables are **always** attached to a scope. We usually say that a variable is "global" when it's in the *module scope*.

The widest scope is the built-in scope, so it would be theoretically possible for you to add something as a built-in. However this is a **really** bad practice.
Also it doesn't complete fix the problem, because all files could *access* that new built-in, but they couldn't re-assign it without explicitly mentioning the scope.